# How to modify JavaScript object name?

Tags: javascript, object, jscript

In JavaScript I have following code:

```
var rights = {
    'One': [ 1, 1, 0],
    'Two': [ 1, 0, 0],
    'Three': [ 0, 1, 1 ]
};
```

And printing:

```
for (item in rights) Response.Write(item + ' = ' + rights[item] + '<br />');
```

Also, I can access any element in object by this:

```
rights['One'] or rights[0]
```

But how can I iterate through this object makeing indexes lowercased so that it becomes as follows:

```
var rights = {
    'one': [ 1, 1, 0],
    'two': [ 1, 0, 0],
    'three': [ 0, 1, 1 ]
};
```

Answer (score 5):

You can't directly change a key.  You can get the key and its value, set a new key with lowercase key value and then remove the original key.

```
var rights = {
    'One': [ 1, 1, 0],
    'Two': [ 1, 0, 0],
    'Three': [ 0, 1, 1 ]
};

for (var key in rights) {
    var keyLower = key.toLowerCase();
    // if key is not already lower case
    if (keyLower !== key) {
        var temp = rights[key];
        delete rights[key];
        rights[keyLower] = temp;
    }
}

// all keys in the rights object will now be lowercase
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/U9vFQ/

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var key in rights) {

key = key.toLowerCase();

}
```

here is fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/btevfik/JBAXr/

---

ok this doesn't actually update the key. just gives you the key in lowercase.

Answer (score 0):

```
var fieldNames = [];
for (item in rights) { fieldNames.push(item); }
for(i = 0; i < fieldNames.length; i++) {
    var fieldName = fieldNames[i];
    var value = rights[fieldName];
    delete rights[fieldName];

    rights[fieldName.toLowerCase()] = value;    
}
```

Comment: Yeah, it's redundant, I just don't like the idea when you iterate through array and change it in the same time, it could be misleading. I have C# and a little Java background so it seems in js world it's fine :)